# Can not access IP address of Node.js from real Android device

Tags: android, node.js, connection, ip

I set up a very basic node.js server with the following code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 8000;
const ip = '192.16x.xxx.yyy'; // the x's and y's are placeholders. I didnt want to write my real IP here
const http = require("http").createServer();

const io = require("socket.io")(http);


// using the socket, we can send/receive data to/from the client
// the server listens for the "connection" event
io.on("connection", (socket) => {

    // emit an event called "welcome" with a string as data to the client using its socket
    // so, whenever the client connects to the server, it receives this welcome message
    socket.emit("welcome", "Hello and Welcome to the Socket.io server.");

    console.log("a new client is connected.")
});

// the server listens on the specified port for incoming events
http.listen(port, ip, () => {

    console.log("Server is listening on " + ip + ":" + port);

});
```

So, the server is listening for the "connection" event and sends a welcome message when a client connects to the server.

The client which is an Android app looks like this:

```
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.IO;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket;
import com.github.nkzawa.emitter.Emitter;


import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Socket mSocket;
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        try {
            /*
            * IO.socket() returns a socket for the specified URL and port with the
            * default options. Notice that the method caches the result, so you can
            * always get a same Socket instance for an url from any Activity or
            * Fragment.
            * */
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.16x.xxx.yyy:8000");

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        /*
        * We then can make the socket listen an event on onCreate lifecycle callback.
        * */
        mSocket.on("welcome", onNewMessage);


        /*
        * And we explicitly call "connect()" to establish the connection here.
        * In this app, we use onCreate lifecycle callback for that, but it
        * actually depends on your application.
        * */
        mSocket.connect();
    }

    private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String message = (String) args[0];
                    mTextView.setText("Received from Server: " + message);

                }
            });
        }
    };

    /*
    * Since an Android Activity has its own lifecycle, we should carefully manage the
    * state of the socket also to avoid problems like memory leaks. In this app, we’ll
    * close the socket connection and remove all listeners on onDestroy callback of
    * Activity.
    * */
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        // socket gets disconnected
        mSocket.disconnect();

        // off() removes the listener of the "welcome" event
        mSocket.off("welcome", onNewMessage);

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

The client code is also very simple: It connects to the server and displays the message it gets from the server. 
I got this ex. from the official Socket.IO website at https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/.

When I start the server with `node server.js` on the terminal of my laptop and use an Android emulator, then everything works fine.

But when I connect my real Android device to my laptop using a USB then the connection does not take place.

Why Android app (running within the real device) does not connect to the server ?

Comment: You are using a Localhost IP adress, is your Laptop and your device in the same Network?

Comment: yes, they are. I am at home. Both devices (laptop and android device) are connected to the same WiFi .

Comment: WHen you are using locahost you can Change your node.js IP to 127.0.0.1

Comment: tested. not working.

Comment: Sorry was my fault, IP 0.0.0.0 should be your node.js IP. You Need to connect to your localhost from your device than, in your router youcan see the IP of your laptop

Comment: again, also tested & not working

Comment: Some wifi routers need to be configured so inter client connections are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: I created a socket with the IP 0.0.0.0, You should Change your IP at your node.js to this value.

Than i opened cmd and entered ipconfig to see what my ip adress is, this is your local IP adress. In the Code i am connecting to this IP Adress.

For example if you see IP 192.168.178.50 in your ipconfig you Change your Android Code to

```
mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.178.50:8000");
```

And your Node.js Code should look like

```
const ip = '0.0.0.0';
```

And dont Forget to Restart your Server when you changed the node.js code